# Is there a way to use junit.extensions.TestSetup for tests on Android?

Tags: android, junit

The android sdk source includes source for junit.extensions, but the classes are not in android.jar even though junit.framework and junit.runner are in there.  I tried creating my own junit.extensions package and using the source included in the android sdk source, but I get a ClassCastException (see below).  Something in android.test.suitebuilder is trying to cast the return value from the suite() method to a TestCase, even though suite returns a Test interface.

I want to use TestSetup class from junit.extensions, as in the following example (see http://etutorials.org/Programming/Java+extreme+programming/Chapter+4.+JUnit/4.7+One-Time+Set+Up+and+Tear+Down/):

```
public SomeTestCase extends TestCase {

  public static Test suite() {
    TestSetup setup = new TestSetup(new TestSuite(SomeTestCase.class)) {
      @Override
      protected void setUp(  ) throws Exception {
          // do your one-time setup here!
      }

      @Override
      protected void tearDown(  ) throws Exception {
          // do your one-time tear down here!
      }
    };
    return setup;
  }

  public void someTestMethod() { }

}
```

However, I get the following error:

```
05-21 08:10:14.152: I/TestRunner(1316): java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception during suite construction
05-21 08:10:14.152: I/TestRunner(1316):     at android.test.suitebuilder.TestSuiteBuilder$FailedToCreateTests.testSuiteConstructionFailed(TestSuiteBuilder.java:238)
05-21 08:10:14.152: I/TestRunner(1316):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-21 08:10:14.152: I/TestRunner(1316):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-21 08:10:14.152: I/TestRunner(1316):     at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:154)
05-21 08:10:14.152: I/TestRunner(1316):     at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:127)
05-21 08:10:14.152: I/TestRunner(1316):     at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:106)
05-21 08:10:14.152: I/TestRunner(1316):     at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:124)
05-21 08:10:14.152: I/TestRunner(1316):     at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:109)
05-21 08:10:14.152: I/TestRunner(1316):     at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:118)
05-21 08:10:14.152: I/TestRunner(1316):     at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:169)
05-21 08:10:14.152: I/TestRunner(1316):     at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:154)
05-21 08:10:14.152: I/TestRunner(1316):     at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:545)
05-21 08:10:14.152: I/TestRunner(1316):     at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1551)
05-21 08:10:14.152: I/TestRunner(1316): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.somebody.test.SomeTestCase$1 cannot be cast to junit.framework.TestCase
05-21 08:10:14.152: I/TestRunner(1316):     at android.test.suitebuilder.TestSuiteBuilder.build(TestSuiteBuilder.java:188)
05-21 08:10:14.152: I/TestRunner(1316):     at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onCreate(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:379)
05-21 08:10:14.152: I/TestRunner(1316):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:3920)
05-21 08:10:14.152: I/TestRunner(1316):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:123)
05-21 08:10:14.152: I/TestRunner(1316):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1185)
05-21 08:10:14.152: I/TestRunner(1316):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-21 08:10:14.152: I/TestRunner(1316):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-21 08:10:14.152: I/TestRunner(1316):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
05-21 08:10:14.152: I/TestRunner(1316):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-21 08:10:14.152: I/TestRunner(1316):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-21 08:10:14.152: I/TestRunner(1316):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
05-21 08:10:14.152: I/TestRunner(1316):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
05-21 08:10:14.152: I/TestRunner(1316):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The suite() method of a TestCase is supposed to return a Test, but it appears something in android os is trying to cast it to a TestCase.

As one attempt to resolve the problem, I tweaked the TestDecorator class so that it subclassed TestCase instead of Test, but it still gave the same ClassCastException, which really mystified me.

By the way, there seems to be some doubt about android.jar containing junit, so here is a partial listing of android.jar contents:

```
$ jar tf android.jar | more
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
assets/
assets/images/
assets/images/android-logo-mask.png
assets/images/android-logo-shine.png
assets/sounds/
assets/sounds/bootanim1.raw
assets/sounds/bootanim0.raw
assets/webkit/
assets/webkit/android-weberror.png
assets/webkit/togglePlugin.png
assets/webkit/nullPlugin.png
assets/webkit/youtube.html
assets/webkit/missingImage.png
assets/webkit/youtube.png
assets/webkit/textAreaResizeCorner.png
assets/webkit/play.png
junit/
junit/framework/
junit/framework/TestSuite.class
junit/framework/ComparisonFailure.class
junit/framework/Assert.class
junit/framework/TestListener.class
junit/framework/TestResult.class
junit/framework/Test.class
junit/framework/TestFailure.class
junit/framework/Protectable.class
junit/framework/TestCase.class
junit/framework/AssertionFailedError.class
junit/runner/
junit/runner/TestSuiteLoader.class
junit/runner/Version.class
junit/runner/BaseTestRunner.class
```

You can also see it listed in the package contents on the android reference site at https://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html.  If you continue to doubt, please browse your copy of android.jar.

Any helpful suggestions? Has anyone successfully used junit.extensions.TestSetup with android?

Comment: as far as I know, JUnit is not included in the Android SDK, but rather with Eclipse.

Comment: junit.framework and junit.runner packages are in android.jar for sdk 10.  But the source tree for android sdk 10 includes junit.awtui, junit.extensions, junit.swingui, junit.textui as well as junit.framework and junit.runner.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for posting those details.

Comment: I'll look into this some more.  I worked with android awhile ago, my experience may have been different :)  Have you tried the ever-insisted project cleanup/fix project properties?

Comment: Try renaming "SomeTestCase" to something in the form of "Testxxxxx".  I am fairly sure JUnit requires all test class names to be in that format.  Just an idea :)

Comment: Tried renaming, but no luck.  The error message specifically says that it is a class cast exception when the anonymous TestSetup class instance is being cast to TestCase.  In a regular java junit test project setup, that would work.  This error is specific to android.

Comment: Hi Chuck, out of curiousity, how did you even include the junit.extensions.TestSetup?  Did you reference the Android SDK source?  I guess in the meantime we have to kludge setup/teardown methods by naming them testAAAsetup and testZZZteardown?  There's also a [Junit4 for Android](https://github.com/dthommes/JUnit4Android) hack if you didn't already know about it.

Comment: I used the source from the Android SDK and put it in my test project in a package called junit.extensions.  However, it appears that the test runner does not accept the object returned, you get a ClassCastException.  I did not know about the hack for using junit4.  Thanks for passing that along.

Comment: Looks like this problem is due to an unsafe cast on line 88 here https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/cccf2a333793badbcea9b04fe3f29447496a56d9/test-runner/src/android/test/suitebuilder/TestSuiteBuilder.java

It looks like the `TestSuiteBuilder` code assumes that a `TestSuite` can only contain `TestSuite` instances or `TestCase` instances (because it's filtering TestCase instances). I don't know enough about Android to know if you can run tests without `TestSuiteBuilder`.

Comment: You are correct.  It appears that Android did not meet this expectation.  I gave up on trying to solve this issue.

Comment: Hey, could you figured out an alternative way for using TestSetup in android? I'm running into the same problem here..

Comment: @FelipeMosso Sorry, but I never succeeded in finding a way to do this. Gave up after a few days of trying.

Comment: :(
thanks anyway! if I find something I will answer this question.. but I'm almost giving up as well..